# How to send audio and image file with email attachment?

Tags: android, android-intent, email

I am trying to send an email with attachment of sound file and image file. I am able to attach both of files, but when I am trying to send it that time I am getting pop up message "Unfortunately Gmail has stopped."

The code is here :-

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.setType("Audio/mp3");
intent.setType("image/png");

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Attachment from app");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sending mp3 file ");

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
        new String[] { "xxx@gmail.com" });
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(mFileName.getAbsolutePath())));
uris.add(Uri.parse(picturePath.toString()));
//intent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(picturePath.toString()));


intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

// startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail"));
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail"),
        EMAIL_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing google and RND I solved the issue. Follow this code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    intent.setType("Audio/mp3");
    intent.setType("image/jpg");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Attachment from app");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sending mp3 file ");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
            new String[] { "xxx@gmail.com" });
    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
            String[] filePaths = new String[]{mFileName.getAbsolutePath(),picturePath.toString()};
    for (String file : filePaths) {
        File fileIn = new File(file);
        Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
        uris.add(u);
    }
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail"),
            EMAIL_REQUEST );
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail"),
            RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE );
```

Answer (score 0):

to send try this code

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"email"});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Test");
//has to be an ArrayList
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
//convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
 for (String file : filePaths)
{
File fileIn = new File(file);
Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
uris.add(u);
}
 emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
 context.startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

`intent.setType("audio/mpeg")`  for mp3 files, look MIME types!

Comment: it is a comment not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Use settype is *.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.setType("*/*");


intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Attachment from app");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sending mp3 file ");

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
        new String[] { "xxx@gmail.com" });
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(mFileName.getAbsolutePath())));
uris.add(Uri.parse(picturePath.toString()));
//intent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(picturePath.toString()));


intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

// startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail"));
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail"),
        EMAIL_REQUEST);
```